# Unknown problem causing major computer failure, Booting problem with windows 7, mainly with 0x0000000A

Tags: windows-7, boot, bsod

Where do I begin?

OS=Windows 7

I think it all started when I ran an installation file. I suspect it may have been a virus (even though AVG scan didnt pick anything up). The installation failed, computer crashed then restarted.

In the middle of the reboot, I get BSOD. Normal boot up doesnt work so I use safe mode.

Method 1: Not a problem I thought cos I will do what I normally do and that was to recover from my image file. Unfortunately, my Acronis software cant recover in safe mode.

Method 2: I created a bootable disc for the Acronis recovery software. Managed to boot to Acronis and started the recovery from image file. This fail with some error message (did not manage to record). Something to do with not be able to copy to $AVG folder.

Method 3: At this stage, assumed it was still a virus causing the problem so decided to format that partition to remove everything and hopefully the virus too. Had a lot of problems trying to bypass the system to allow me to format but (i think- more on this later) I managed to do that. Image was recovered, thought problem was resolved. Tried to boot windows but new error: Boot Manager is missing. Read up on this and managed to copy the Boot Manager from my Laptop's Manufacturer's partition (partition contains factory setup image file). Windows loaded but new BSOD with 0x000000A problem.

Method 4: Attempted to reinstall factory settings but this failed cos i suspect by formating the partition, I may have removed the recovery software. Tried to create a bootable dvd of factory setting but machine is so bad it continues to crash. Bootable dvd method failed.

Method 5:Spent alot of time reading up on this error, even installed a software to help scan and fix the problem. Scan failed and software required money! Anyway, lots of BSOD with different error message like 0x00000001A and 0x0000000D1. Error message changes with some reboots.

Method 6: Found a hotfix from the windows site to fix 0x0000000A problem, great I thought! In safe mode, I cant install the file cos of error:0x8007043c. Tried to then install the fix in normal mode but installation just hangs. Returned to safe mode and followed advice to bypass 0x8007043c by changing the BITS status (read here: http://www.vistaheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-windowsupdate/181931-error-number-0x8007043c-windows-update.html). However, my machine at this time is so flaky that it hangs everytime i right mouse click the computer icon.

I am at my wits end. Ya help or ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Get your hands on a retail copy of Windows 7 (the same bit-level and version as yours) and try to do a repair from the disc's boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

You might try doing a regular Windows install and then extract your private files from the .tib. You would lose all of your installed software and probably all of your settings.

I hope your .tib backup file is saved on a separate hard drive or something.

Answer (score 0):

Use the W7 DVD to do a startup repair, it may take up to 3 startup repairs in a row before the system is bootable again.

http://www.windowsreinstall.com/win7/windows7ultimaterepairguides/

Answer (score 0):

thanks for you replies.

I have managed to borrow win 7 installation disc and used that to repair but with no luck. However, the disc did open up new repair options, noteably my laptop's own recovery software. I have managed to recover the laptop back to its factory setting!!!

At last! That was the most difficult repair I have ever done but I learnt alot!!! Thanks for ya support. What a great website!